# The graphics in Need for Speed: Hot Pursuit 2010 are too dark. How do I fix this?

Tags: pc, need-for-speed-hot-pursuit-2010

My PC configuration is:

- CORE 2 Quad 1.8GHz
- 2GB RAM
- Intel G41RQ Motherboard (G41 Chipset)
- Intel® Graphics Media Accelerator X4500 integrated graphics subsystem

---

I have installed Hot Pursuit 2010. The game is running but the screen is so dark. It seems like I'm racing at night. Is this a problem with my built in graphics card?

Comment: OS: Windows 7 ultimate.

Comment: if you want to add additional information to a question/answer please use the Edit link.

Answer (score 2):

I got the solution :D
I just installed latest Graphics Driver from Intel site. and now its working fine.